# node socket app new instance scope

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, socket.io

it is a simple socket app using event base pattern

```
const invitation = require('./invitation');
module.exports = function(io){
    io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
        var prepareGame = new PrepareGame(socket)
        socket.on("sendInvitation",(data, ack)=>{
            prepareGame.sendInvitation(data,ack)
        });
    });
}
```

and in prepareGame.js

```
const events = require('events');
const util = require('util');

class PrepareGame extends events {
    constructor(socket) {
        super();
        this.user = socket.user
        var self = this

        draftInvitation(data){
            this.newInvitation = {
                from_user: self.user.id,
                to_user: data.to_user,
                message:data.message,
                created_at:moment().unix(),
            }
            return this
        };

        self.on("toSocket", (eventName, clientId, data) => {
            console.log(` ===>>>> sending to listener ${eventName}`, clientId);
            var client  = users[clientId]
            if(client)
                client.emit(eventName, data)
        });

    }

    // public function
    sendInvitation(data, ack) {
        // console.log(this);
        var self = this
        data.message = 'New Invitation'
        draftInvitation(data)
        .emit("toSocket", "getInvitation", data.to_user, self.newInvitation)

        setTimeout(()=>{
            data.message = 'Invitation timeout'
            draftInvitation(data)
            .emit("toSocket", "getInvitation", self.user.id, self.newInvitation)
        }, 15000)

        if(typeof ack == 'function')
            ack({
                status:200,
                message: "invitation sent",
            })
    }
}

util.inherits(PrepareGame, events.EventEmitter )

module.exports =  PrepareGame
```

code is sum of different design pattern. it's working fine but I've some queries

1. io.connection called once to connect to socket and prepareGame
   instance created. considering two instance for two user then
   **how sendInvitation automatically bound correct instance when calling**
2. what happen with new prepareGame instance when socket disconnect ?
3. i want to remove `(data, ack)=>{ }` encloser from socket.on mean it
   should  socket.on ("sendInvitation",prepareGame.sendInvitation) then
   how to manage this reference in sendInvitation function